# Custom link function for logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, link-function

I am trying to build a generalized linear model with a custom link function. This is a follow up to this question: [Understand and specify a generalized logistic model in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/637758/32477)

In this paper [A Generalized Mixed Logistic Model for Predicting Individual Tree Survival Probability with Unequal Measurement Intervals](https://doi.org/10.5849/forsci.10-092) ) by Yuqing Yang and Shongming Huang, the authors provide two models. The first one (Eq. 1 in the paper) is this:

$$P = \left( \frac{e^\eta}{1 + e^\eta} \right)^{L}$$,
where $\eta$ is the linear predictor and $L$ the time duration between measurements.

For this model the following custom link function by @BenBolker works fine (https://rpubs.com/bbolker/logregexp):

```
logexp <- function(exposure = 1) {
  ## hack to help with visualization, post-prediction etc etc
  get_exposure <- function() {
    if (exists("..exposure", envir = .GlobalEnv))
      return(get("..exposure", envir = .GlobalEnv))
    exposure
  }
  ################ RELEVANT PART ARE HERE: ################
  linkfun <- function(mu)
    qlogis(mu ^ (1 / get_exposure()))

  linkinv <- function(eta)
    plogis(eta) ^ get_exposure()

  logit_mu_eta <- function(eta) {
    ifelse(abs(eta) > 30, .Machine$double.eps,
           exp(eta) / (1 + exp(eta)) ^ 2)
  }
  mu.eta <- function(eta) {
    get_exposure() * plogis(eta) ^ (get_exposure() - 1) *
      logit_mu_eta(eta)
  }
  ################ UNTIL HERE ################

  valideta <- function(eta)
    TRUE
  link <- paste("logexp(", deparse(substitute(exposure)), ")",
                sep = "")
  structure(
    list(
      linkfun = linkfun,
      linkinv = linkinv,
      mu.eta = mu.eta,
      valideta = valideta,
      name = link
    ),
    class = "link-glm"
  )
}
```

However, the authors also provide a second modified logistic function (Eq. 2 in the paper):
$$P = \left( \frac{e^\eta}{L + e^\eta} \right)$$

For this I tried to modify the custom link function myself, however, I am **(a) not sure if I have done this correctly**, and **(b) whether this is a statistically sound approach that is presented in the paper**. Here's my attempt to adjust the link function based on Eq. 2 in the paper. I think I might have an incorrect specification of the `logit_mu_eta()` and `mu.eta()` functions:

```
logexp <- function(exposure = 1) {
  get_exposure <- function() {
    if (exists("..exposure", envir = .GlobalEnv))
      return(get("..exposure", envir = .GlobalEnv))
    exposure
  }
  ################ RELEVANT PARTS ARE BELOW ################
  linkfun <- function(mu)
    qlogis(mu) + log(get_exposure())
  
  linkinv <- function(eta)
    exp(eta) / (get_exposure() + exp(eta))
  
  logit_mu_eta <- function(eta) {
    ifelse(abs(eta) > 30, .Machine$double.eps,
           exp(eta) / (get_exposure() + exp(eta)) ^ 2)
  }
  mu.eta <- function(eta) {
    get_exposure() * plogis(eta) ^ (get_exposure() - 1) * logit_mu_eta(eta)
  }
  ################ UNTIL HERE ################

  valideta <- function(eta)
    TRUE
  
  link <- paste("logexp(", deparse(substitute(exposure)), ")",
                sep = "")
  
  structure(
    list(
      linkfun = linkfun,
      linkinv = linkinv,
      logit_mu_eta = logit_mu_eta,
      mu.eta = mu.eta,
      valideta = valideta,
      name = link
    ),
    class = "link-glm"
  )
}
```